# I want to remove onblur and the name (this.form) within the HTML document so when the user clicks the button it just calls the function

Tags: function

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Create a global an global awaay for strCurrency & dblExchange Rate
            var strCurrency=['Yen','US Dollar','Euro','Swiss Frank','Danish Korona'];
            var dblExchangeRate=[128.7, 1.59, 1.15, 2.06, 9.69];

            //Declare the function convert currency 
            function convertCurrency()
            {
                var txtSterling= document.getElementById("txtSterling");
                var selCurrency= document.getElementById("cmbCurrency");
                var txtConversion= document.getElementById ("txtConversion");

                //reset to no value
                txtConversion.value='';

                //validate for numbers
                if(isNaN(txtSterling.value))
                {
                    txtSterling.value='';
                    alert('Please insert a numerical value');
                    txtSterling.focus();
                    return;
                }

                var strCurrency=selCurrency = document.getElementById("cmbCurrency").selectedIndex;
                txtConversion.value = (txtSterling.value * dblExchangeRate[i]).toFixed(2) + ' ' + strCurrency[i];
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Currency Converter</p>
        <form action="">
            &pound; <input type="text" name="txtSterling" onblur="convertCurrency(this.form)">
            <select name="cmbCurrency" onchange="convertCurrency(this.form)">
                <option>Yen</option>
                <option>US Dollars</option>
                <option>Euro</option>
                <option>Swiss Frank</option>
                <option>Danish Korona</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" value="Convert" name="cmdCurrency" onclick="convertCurrency(this.form)">
            <input type="text" name="txtConversion" readonly="readonly">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your convertCurrency function doesn't require any arguments, you don't even need the this.form parameter. Also, you can just remove the blur=... to get rid of the onblur event. The same goes for the select's onchange event, if you wanted to get rid of it as well.

UPDATED: Silly me for copy pasting...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Create a global an global awaay for strCurrency & dblExchange Rate
            var strCurrency=['Yen','US Dollar','Euro','Swiss Frank','Danish Korona'];
            var dblExchangeRate=[128.7, 1.59, 1.15, 2.06, 9.69];

            //Declare the function convert currency 
            function convertCurrency()
            {
                var txtSterling= document.getElementById("txtSterling");
                var selCurrency= document.getElementById("cmbCurrency");
                var txtConversion= document.getElementById ("txtConversion");
                var cmbCurrency = document.getElementById("cmbCurrency");

                //reset to no value
                txtConversion.value='';

                //validate for numbers
                if(isNaN(txtSterling.value))
                {
                    txtSterling.value='';
                    alert('Please insert a numerical value');
                    txtSterling.focus();
                    return;
                }

                var i = cmbCurrency.selectedIndex;
                var strCurrency = cmbCurrency.options[i].text;
                txtConversion.value = (txtSterling.value * dblExchangeRate[i]).toFixed(2) + ' ' + strCurrency;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Currency Converter</p>
        <form action="">
            &pound; <input id="txtSterling" type="text" name="txtSterling">
            <select id="cmbCurrency" name="cmbCurrency" onchange="convertCurrency();">
                <option>Yen</option>
                <option>US Dollars</option>
                <option>Euro</option>
                <option>Swiss Frank</option>
                <option>Danish Korona</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" id="cmdCurrency" value="Convert" name="cmdCurrency" onclick="convertCurrency();">
            <input type="text" id="txtConversion" name="txtConversion" readonly="readonly">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How come it doesn't produce a converted currency?

Comment: I fixed it. The reason is because you're using getElementById but you weren't adding id's to your inputs